# Progress bar Continually looping

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a progress bar which is crashing out I am using a coutner to increment its value based on the value++ method however after changing the code the progress bar just loops and does not display the results into the grid as intended.

```
invoiceRecord = (SageDataObject240.InvoiceRecord)_workSpace.CreateObject(Resources.InvoiceRecord);


pnlProgress.Visible = true;
progBarSelectInvoices.Value = 0;
progBarSelectInvoices.Maximum = invoiceRecord.Count;

List<EdiInvoice> selectedInvoices = new List<EdiInvoice>();
EdiInvoice invoice;

DateTime fromDate = chkEnableFromDatePicker.Checked ? dtpFrom.Value.Date : DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime toDate = chkEnableToDatePicker.Checked ? dtpTo.Value.Date : DateTime.MaxValue;
int count = 0;
while (invoiceRecord.MoveLast())
{
    progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
    bool isPosted = (SDOHelper.Read<sbyte>(invoiceRecord, Resources.POSTED_CODE) == 1);

    if (isPosted)
    {
        int invoiceNo = SDOHelper.Read<int>(invoiceRecord, Resources.INVOICE_NUMBER);
        string invoiceCustomerReference = SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, Resources.ACCOUNT_REF);
        bool isValidCustomerReference = (invoiceCustomerReference == _selectedCustomer.Reference || _selectedCustomer.IncludeBranchInvoices && _selectedCustomer.BranchCodes.ContainsKey(invoiceCustomerReference));

        sbyte invoiceTypeCode = SDOHelper.Read<sbyte>(invoiceRecord, Resources.INVOICE_TYPE_CODE);
        bool isValidType = invoiceTypeCode >= 0 && invoiceTypeCode <= 5;

        string notes1 = SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, "NOTES_1");
        bool isExported = notes1.Length > 2 && notes1.Substring(0, 3).Equals("EDI", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        DateTime invoiceDate = SDOHelper.Read<DateTime>(invoiceRecord, "INVOICE_DATE");
        bool isInDateRange = invoiceDate >= fromDate && invoiceDate <= toDate;

        if (isValidCustomerReference && isValidType && (!isExported || chkIncludeAlreadyExportedInvoices.Checked) && isInDateRange)
        {
            invoice = new EdiInvoice();
            invoice.Customer = string.Format("({0}), {1}", invoiceCustomerReference, SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, Resources.NAME));
            invoice.InvoiceNumber = invoiceNo;
            invoice.Date = SDOHelper.Read<DateTime>(invoiceRecord, "INVOICE_DATE").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            invoice.Type = GetInvoiceOrCredit(invoiceTypeCode);
            invoice.DeliveryAddress = SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, Resources.DEL_ADDRESS_1);
            invoice.Nett = SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_TOT_NET) + SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_CARR_NET);
            invoice.Vat = SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_TOT_TAX) + SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_CARR_TAX);

            selectedInvoices.Add(invoice);
        }
    }






    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I do not understand as to why the progress bar is continually lopping here.

Comment: What do you mean? By reading your code, your progressbar will go from 0 to Maximum directly.

Comment: It just resets it selfs and starts again.

Comment: Have you accidentally set it to Marquee mode? (`progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;`)

Comment: nope just all standard settings its set to block mode.

Comment: @david - When you said "crashing out" did you mean you were getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: If you could supply a [mcve] then other people would be able to replicate your problem, and might be able to help.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents();` is a bit of a code smell. Put your code in a backgroundworker and marshal the updates to the Progress Bar back into the UI thread.

Comment: Doing that now thanks