# Progress bar exceeding max value

Tags: c#, winforms

Progress bar exceeds max value when using the ++ operate to increment the value. In the following code I have a record set which is 6004 in size when it comes round the loop it manages to get to 6006 even though I have put an if statment to trap when it reaches the value++ to reset the progress bar to zero and also hide the panel.

```
    invoiceRecord = (SageDataObject240.InvoiceRecord)_workSpace.CreateObject(Resources.InvoiceRecord);


    pnlProgress.Visible = true;
    progBarSelectInvoices.Value = 0;
    progBarSelectInvoices.Maximum = invoiceRecord.Count;

    List<EdiInvoice> selectedInvoices = new List<EdiInvoice>();
    EdiInvoice invoice;

    DateTime fromDate = chkEnableFromDatePicker.Checked ? dtpFrom.Value.Date : DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTime toDate = chkEnableToDatePicker.Checked ? dtpTo.Value.Date : DateTime.MaxValue;
    int invoiceCount = 0;
    int progressCount = 0;
  int progresbarValue = 0;          
    int maxCount = invoiceRecord.Count + 1;
    while (invoiceRecord.MoveLast())
    {
        progresbarValue = progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
        bool isPosted = (SDOHelper.Read<sbyte>(invoiceRecord, Resources.POSTED_CODE) == 1);

        if (isPosted)
        {
            int invoiceNo = SDOHelper.Read<int>(invoiceRecord, Resources.INVOICE_NUMBER);
            string invoiceCustomerReference = SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, Resources.ACCOUNT_REF);
            bool isValidCustomerReference = (invoiceCustomerReference == _selectedCustomer.Reference || _selectedCustomer.IncludeBranchInvoices && _selectedCustomer.BranchCodes.ContainsKey(invoiceCustomerReference));

            sbyte invoiceTypeCode = SDOHelper.Read<sbyte>(invoiceRecord, Resources.INVOICE_TYPE_CODE);
            bool isValidType = invoiceTypeCode >= 0 && invoiceTypeCode <= 5;

            string notes1 = SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, "NOTES_1");
            bool isExported = notes1.Length > 2 && notes1.Substring(0, 3).Equals("EDI", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

            DateTime invoiceDate = SDOHelper.Read<DateTime>(invoiceRecord, "INVOICE_DATE");
            bool isInDateRange = invoiceDate >= fromDate && invoiceDate <= toDate;

            if (isValidCustomerReference && isValidType && (!isExported || chkIncludeAlreadyExportedInvoices.Checked) && isInDateRange)
            {
                invoice = new EdiInvoice();
                invoice.Customer = string.Format("({0}), {1}", invoiceCustomerReference, SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, Resources.NAME));
                invoice.InvoiceNumber = invoiceNo;
                invoice.Date = SDOHelper.Read<DateTime>(invoiceRecord, "INVOICE_DATE").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                invoice.Type = GetInvoiceOrCredit(invoiceTypeCode);
                invoice.DeliveryAddress = SDOHelper.Read<string>(invoiceRecord, Resources.DEL_ADDRESS_1);
                invoice.Nett = SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_TOT_NET) + SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_CARR_NET);
                invoice.Vat = SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_TOT_TAX) + SDOHelper.Read<double>(invoiceRecord, Resources.BASE_CARR_TAX);

                selectedInvoices.Add(invoice);
            }
        }
           invoiceCount = invoiceRecord.Count;
           progressCount = progBarSelectInvoices.Value;
        if (progressCount++ == maxCount || progressCount==invoiceCount )
        {
            progBarSelectInvoices.Value = 0;
            progressCount = 0;
            pnlProgress.Visible = false;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        else

        {
            progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
            progressCount= progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: You've already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243491/progress-bar-continually-looping)

Comment: @HandbagCrab - I looked at that one too, but it is slightly different, and the unfortunate suggestion there was "add `Application.DoEvents`" I would agree that they are very closely related and solving the one probably solves the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you to figure this out if we walk through what is happening here. Let's examine what happens when you are entering the 6003rd loop.
I will assume that `progBarSelectInvoices.Value == 6002` at this point:

What does this line do?

```
progresbarValue = progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
```

At the end of it. `progresbarValue == 6004` and `progBarSelectInvoices == 6003`

`progresbarValue` is never used again so it could probably just be dumped, but not sure

Then we skip down and do a bunch of other things and hit this line:

```
progressCount = progBarSelectInvoices.Value;
```

Here `progressCount == 6003`  and then we do this:

```
if (progressCount++ == maxCount || progressCount==invoiceCount)
```

So what happens here, if `maxCount == 6004` than the first part of this if is `false` BUT now `progessCount == 6004`. We know that if `maxCount` is 6004, then `invoiceCount == 6003` (from this line `maxCount = invoiceRecord.Count + 1;`), but now `progressCount == 6004` so this is also false.  This means we execute the else part.

```
progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
progressCount= progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
```

What does this do?  Well, in the first line we increment `progBarSelectInvoices.Value` so that is now 6004.  Then we move to the second line where we set `progressCount` to 6004, but then we increment the value of the progress bar again, so it is now 6005.  Then we go back to the top of the loop and the first thing we do is increment the progress bar again, which brings us to 6006.

Personally, I try to avoid doing either pre or post increment statements in if statements as it can make the code hard to read.  In this case, I would definitely advise against it.

**How to fix**
One way to fix this - if you know for sure you only have 6004 records and so you will only execute that while loop 6004 times, then just do this (note, I am recommending that you move the increment to the end of the while loop so that you are actually done the work before indicating progress)

```
while (invoiceRecord.MoveLast())
{
    // All your other code here
    progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
```

If you want to be sure you don't exceed the max value you could just add a quick check

```
while (invoiceRecord.MoveLast())
{
    // All your other code here
    if (progBarSelectInvoices.Value < progBarSelectInvoices.Maximum)
        progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;
```

You can then do away with the if/else business at the end of the loop that is checking the maxCount and either resetting the progress bar or incrementing it.

**Side note**
From the presence of the line `Application.DoEvents()` and the fact that you are not getting an exception when incrementing the progress bar value, I get the sneaky suspicion that you are executing this loop in the UI thread.  Whenever you find yourself needing to add `Application.DoEvents()` in your event handler code, it is a very good time to ask yourself "How can I move this work out of the UI thread?"  Calling `Application.DoEvents()` is almost never a good idea.  See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357292/avoid-application-doevents-in-c-sharp)

You should move that code into a background thread.  The only thing to keep in mind is that you would need to use an invoke call to update the progress bar value.

Comment: Hi that is exactly what is happening how would you recommend I get around this or fix this.the sdo object I am using only has a movenext function I am afraid.

Comment: @david - It is hard to answer that as you only posted part of the code, so I just walked you through what is happening. If you know for sure that you have only 6004 records, then start it at 0 and increment it once per loop. No need for the if statements setting it back to 0. If you finish your loop and you fell short, just set it to max value at the end.

Comment: its still gave me an error it still got 6006 so it did with the code above.

Comment: @david - Did you remove all of the other `progBarSelectInvoices.Value++;` lines. You should only have that line once in the code. Also, I just updated the if statement that should protect from this. I didn't realize that `maxCount` would actually be 6005 not 6004, as your record count is 6004 and maxCount is 1 greater than that.